# How to type a map where the type of the value depends on the type of the key?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to type a `Map<K, V>` in such a way where the type of the value will depend on the type of the key, without specifying the type of the key on creation of the map?

#### Example:

```js
abstract class BaseA { a() {} }
class ConcreteA1 extends BaseA { a1() {} }
class ConcreteA2 extends BaseA { a2() {} }
abstract class BaseB { b() {} }
class ConcreteB extends BaseB { b1() {} }

const map = new Map<???, ???>();
map.set(BaseA, ConcreteA1); // should be OK
map.set(BaseA, ConcreteA2); // should be OK
map.set(BaseB, ConcreteB);  // should be OK

map.set(BaseA, ConcreteB); // should error
```

#### Bonus: can we make be an error too?

Since `BaseA` is abstract, this should be an error as well, if possible, as `BaseA` does not satisfy `new (...args: any[]) => BaseA`, since it is not instantiable.

```
map.set(BaseA, BaseA); // should error as a bonus
```

#### UPDATE:

I need to keep a map of dependency implementations, such as the values are concrete implementations (extend) of the key (base type).

Comment: `class abstract BaseA {}` is invalid TypeScript.  Please ensure that your code constitutes a [mre] suitable for pasting into an IDE.

Comment: Moreover, your classes are all structurally identical to the empty object type, so there's [not a lot of distinction between them in the type system](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).  Please add some structural differences to them.

Comment: Assuming you fix those... the [TS typings for `Map`](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c0072aad8073f/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) don't represent such a correlation, so you'd have to define your own if you want something else (not dissimilar to what's going on in [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/54907009/2887218)). But can you explain the correlation more explicitly and give some more use cases doing stuff other than just `set()`? I could throw something together like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGVrXm), but if you need something more you should say what that is.

Comment: thanks @jcalz, copy-paste issue was fixed.
as for the structure, it was not included for the sake of simplification of the idea.
To clarify I have added some code above.
Also added the use case.

Comment: @jcalz what you provided [here](https://tsplay.dev/WGVrXm) looks like a good solution to me. Many thanks! if you submit it as an answer I will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TypeScript typings for `Map`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c0072aad8073f/lib/lib.es2015.collection.d.ts#L21-L29) only support `Map<K, V>`, where `K` is the key type, `V` is the value type, and there is no further correlation between them.  So if you just use `Map` as-is, you cannot get the TypeScript compiler to enforce extra constraints.

From my reading of your question, I understand your constraint to be that the key should be a (possibly abstract) constructor type, and that for each key, the value should be a (necessarily concrete) constructor of a compatible type.  And since your example code only uses the `set()` method, the minimum typings to get your example code to behave as desired look like this:

```
interface MySpecialMap {
  set<T extends object>(
    k: abstract new (...args: any) => T, 
    v: new (...args: any) => T
  ): this;
}
interface MySpecialMapConstructor {
  new(): MySpecialMap;
}
const MySpecialMap: MySpecialMapConstructor = Map;
```

Here I've defined the `MySpecialMap` constructor to be just the `Map` constructor at runtime, but I've given it the type `MySpecialMapConstructor`, which constructs instances of `MySpecialMap`.  The `MySpecialMap` interface has only one method, `set()`, which is [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of the base class instances.  The `k` parameter is a [possibly `abstract` constructor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-2.html#abstract-construct-signatures) of type `T` instances, while the `v` parameter is a necessarily concrete constructor of type `T` instances.

Let's demonstrate that it works as desired:

```
abstract class BaseA { a() { } }
class ConcreteA1 extends BaseA { a1() { } }
class ConcreteA2 extends BaseA { a2() { } }
abstract class BaseB { b() { } }
class ConcreteB extends BaseB { b1() { } }

const map = new MySpecialMap();
map.set(BaseA, ConcreteA1); // ok
map.set(BaseA, ConcreteA2); // ok
map.set(BaseB, ConcreteB);  // ok
map.set(BaseA, ConcreteB); // error
// Property 'a' is missing in type 'ConcreteB' but required in type 'BaseA'
map.set(BaseA, BaseA); // error
// Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.
```

Looks good!

After this you presumably want to add similar typings for `get()` or any other methods you need. Or you might want to change the call signature for `set()` to specify zero-arg constructors or any other constraint you want to enforce.  But hopefully this should get you started.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DKAHCDhwA2qc2yA3gLABQyyAzhGADwAqyEAHpCACb3IA9gCMAVnjAA+ABQBrAFzI4w+mCiIwyEBADuyaQDojcKAHN6iuCHQBKZAF5JyVgBpkAN0Xa9h42YtK1naOzjaKYAAWwPQA3DQAvjSgkLCIKBg4eATEpADCgiCqUACuCGCCUBQ0dN7SYWhYuPhEJNhx1InUCAWqDZnNOdiKGU3ZrfmFaqXllfZopO00ykUayAiEcPQCAEKbEACCFEp1R-HIneubAhMIUEwHAIwc3BB8O3uH5EoPJ19nFxstsgbndIPsAEzPHj8ZC7RifJTg37nc5LFRqVaXIFwiDbI7CZH-GhY64FW73PFcaHvRh4r7CH52P6o6jEnqaAC2pAcWl0fVGLVIdXaXOwBkYYGkOP2bhB932DxsMWQAHoVUJZDRReKmFKPrKyaCDuClar1YJNdRtRK9bSDSByZBtqazRqtaQdZLpfbHbjTWqOFAoBU3AAFYO4KBgdDIADkcFjyGiyA50XooFMSZAyGjuDjcqdieExU0dwAjsVgHdeFmc+g87HpbH3WKbd7YR9-eroMGoLKrCBBJorsBTNmrEp0eoymt2SUyhU63nykotAUALTLDEz7qTeczJcQAw0GhAA)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is a Structural Type System. A structural type system means that when comparing types, TypeScript only takes into account the members on the type. This is in contrast to nominal type systems, where you could create two types but could not assign them to each other. (Read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#example/structural-typing))

In order to go passed that you can uniquify your base class (e.g. adding a private member `#type`). Using that, you can create a new type that would only allow certain maps to exist.
Here's an example:

```js
abstract class BaseA {
    #type = BaseA.name;
}
class ConcreteA extends BaseA {
}
abstract class BaseB {}
class ConcreteB extends BaseB {
}

type MyMap<T, S> = S extends T ? Map<T, S> : never; 
const map1: MyMap<BaseA, ConcreteA> = new Map();
//    ^?
const map2: MyMap<BaseA, ConcreteB> = new Map();
//    ^?
```

Link to the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgQmgpgQQQG8AoBMhAYggE8AHHBAXi1zwDoA7YAWxwG5iAX2Io0GAMIB7DrCg4I%20BDgAeCjgBMM2MIpLDQkGPCSp0LHZiLDRZqTLkLLKtZvM5Le4sRr0EAWWo-YFoAHgAVABoEAGUAPiYYpVUcDQwwhAB%20f2DwqLiEAC4EDhwANxwoPgQRaUgEbmCARiKAoNDtfCi7WXl8eOYSgHds2gAKAEoBAHop8gQAPQyajjqG2gAmFsCcjrwu6R7HfuKcYbaJ6dnyReIgA)

Comment: thanks @SytaxError, however this does not solve the problem in hand. it makes sure I cannot define a map where the value does not implement the key, but it requires all keys to be instances of a certain type (rather than classes) and the values to be instances that extend the typeof the key (rather than class that extend it)